# ! Dimension too large. for tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

MY aim is to plot only a small part of a data set with `tikz` but I get the error message `! Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgf@xx` when I try limit the plot area with `xmin` and `xmax`.
Is there a way to plot my data set with `tikz`? I'm already using `tikz` for all my other data in the document and it seems to be quite inconsistent to use for a single diagram a different tool or design. This particular plot shows only a small part of the data and is normalized to nanosencods. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
/net22 X,/net22 Y
0,1.02826216146185
4.331319308127319e-10,1.025595622568344
5.019136824735054e-10,1.025111934866457
6.394771857950523e-10,1.024007498889289
7.398554712989986e-10,1.023075577928214
8.583054108782335e-10,1.021843167895365
1.026427625279524e-09,1.019878594742247
1.175565037914328e-09,1.0179605576024
1.351354116919862e-09,1.015546548552447
1.594285380510821e-09,1.01206577259123
1.959949157603062e-09,1.006856077470933
2.356838910393234e-09,1.00166954938047
2.652546177571678e-09,0.9983209342962833
2.922080949098272e-09,0.995757674237659
3.182111086403913e-09,0.9937702321468064
3.440448014594548e-09,0.9922711538444744
3.711816987672119e-09,0.9911786446724034
4.006612198819403e-09,0.9904898827842833
4.339130588465944e-09,0.9902282894968941
4.738531257358337e-09,0.9904510268542126
5.333367998864634e-09,0.9913939730692772
5.803571328059038e-09,0.9923682360412974
6.277404020822525e-09,0.9933270420931612
6.73094944437229e-09,0.9940944135556163
7.174592835913752e-09,0.9946431953278941
7.637860895131457e-09,0.994992493329386
8.143984952344972e-09,0.9951459771039093
8.734058640251291e-09,0.9951088776132965
9.512513843471484e-09,0.9948803911645306
1.039956361510021e-08,0.9945768448822899
1.132030797643451e-08,0.9943505241249664
1.219318961264376e-08,0.9942570465719639
1.313178033099918e-08,0.9942612659118217
1.429368459685971e-08,0.9943309014821656
1.657015023652314e-08,0.9944312704679185
1.837899409640984e-08,0.9944426577451113
2.030654181577978e-08,0.9944214555407267
2.315380905065453e-08,0.9943996768306217
2.732743205663546e-08,0.9943995543440359
3.189152964187356e-08,0.9944054855786713
4.101972481234976e-08,0.994406302505255
5.265870592437432e-08,0.9944053208789571
7.593666814842344e-08,0.9944053356389847
1.188183335701361e-07,0.9944053902724225
2.045816644135613e-07,0.9944053829371198
3.761083261004119e-07,0.9944053826446062
5.761083261004118e-07,0.9944053827390887
7.761083261004118e-07,0.9944053827370866
9.761083261004119e-07,0.9944053827369277
1.176108326100412e-06,0.994405382736939
1.376108326100412e-06,0.994405382736939
1.576108326100412e-06,0.9944053827369391
1.776108326100412e-06,0.9944053827369397
1.976108326100412e-06,0.9944053827369395
2.176108326100412e-06,0.9944053827369393
2.376108326100412e-06,0.9944053827369391
2.576108326100412e-06,0.9944053827369387
2.776108326100413e-06,0.9944053827369388
2.976108326100413e-06,0.9944053827369389
3.176108326100413e-06,0.9944053827369386
3.376108326100413e-06,0.9944053827369386
3.576108326100414e-06,0.9944053827369388
3.776108326100414e-06,0.9944053827369389
3.976108326100414e-06,0.9944053827369388
4.176108326100414e-06,0.9944053827369397
4.376108326100413e-06,0.9944053827369387
4.576108326100413e-06,0.9944053827369387
4.776108326100413e-06,0.9944053827369387
4.976108326100413e-06,0.9944053827369388
5.176108326100413e-06,0.9944053827369387
5.376108326100412e-06,0.9944053827369386
5.576108326100412e-06,0.9944053827369385
5.776108326100412e-06,0.9944053827369383
5.976108326100412e-06,0.9944053827369386
6.176108326100411e-06,0.9944053827369389
6.376108326100411e-06,0.9944053827369388
6.576108326100411e-06,0.9944053827369385
6.776108326100411e-06,0.9944053827369385
6.976108326100411e-06,0.9944053827369388
7.17610832610041e-06,0.9944053827369389
7.37610832610041e-06,0.9944053827369388
7.57610832610041e-06,0.9944053827369385
7.776108326100411e-06,0.9944053827369393
7.97610832610041e-06,0.9944053827369393
8.17610832610041e-06,0.9944053827369385
8.37610832610041e-06,0.9944053827369387
8.57610832610041e-06,0.9944053827369388
8.776108326100409e-06,0.9944053827369388
8.976108326100409e-06,0.9944053827369383
9.176108326100409e-06,0.9944053827369386
9.376108326100409e-06,0.9944053827369389
9.576108326100409e-06,0.9944053827369387
9.776108326100408e-06,0.9944053827369386
9.888054163050205e-06,0.9944053827369391
1e-05,0.9944053827369387
1.000000031305744e-05,0.9945026442743422
1.000000034044997e-05,0.9945123027671998
1.000000038140491e-05,0.9945273197625016
1.000000042051929e-05,0.9945422748065738
1.000000046366599e-05,0.9945592799216566
1.000000050047185e-05,0.9945740634174881
1.000000053641175e-05,0.9945886323471639
1.000000057460895e-05,0.9946041646469259
1.000000061627338e-05,0.994621078788969
1.000000066304477e-05,0.9946399535511581
1.000000071615235e-05,0.994661170029568
1.000000077698145e-05,0.9946851165182624
1.000000084755945e-05,0.994712310457373
1.000000092353141e-05,0.99474067311982
1.0000001e-05,0.9947680624004441
1.000000100391882e-05,0.9947693904672034
1.000000100806786e-05,0.9947707632190462
1.000000101497031e-05,0.9947729466221733
1.000000102541984e-05,0.9947760124171113
1.000000103920431e-05,0.9947796433614234
1.00000010526573e-05,0.9947827717512592
1.000000106696285e-05,0.9947856944710599
1.000000108279457e-05,0.9947884993724078
1.000000110082991e-05,0.9947912154962885
1.000000112139743e-05,0.9947937800929507
1.000000114307349e-05,0.994795963858575
1.000000116589546e-05,0.9947977842298714
1.000000119003025e-05,0.9947992703274012
1.000000121565269e-05,0.9948004469168495
1.000000124305054e-05,0.9948013382392805
1.000000127252544e-05,0.9948019618074956
1.00000013044161e-05,0.994802330869087
1.000000133913125e-05,0.9948024554653568
1.000000137717766e-05,0.9948023424047657
1.000000141798923e-05,0.9948020069292224
1.000000146469327e-05,0.9948014294369252
1.00000015174084e-05,0.9948006070984314
1.000000157759394e-05,0.9947995245447283
1.000000161749989e-05,0.9947987479204673
1.000000163509705e-05,0.9947983941799829
1.000000164640024e-05,0.9947981642283803
1.000000165604756e-05,0.9947979665982661
1.000000166612771e-05,0.994797758928084
1.000000167674457e-05,0.9947975390185879
1.000000169797828e-05,0.9947970960193985
1.000000173992938e-05,0.9947962112497323
1.000000178918952e-05,0.9947951619841334
1.000000184193857e-05,0.9947940332176113
1.000000188524007e-05,0.9947931068422322
1.00000019177271e-05,0.9947924137602339
1.000000198270115e-05,0.9947910374626118
1.000000206894388e-05,0.9947892365649708
1.000000215577018e-05,0.9947874578409843
1.00000022410274e-05,0.9947857472830879
1.000000232458782e-05,0.9947841063002641
1.000000240667773e-05,0.9947825283986764
1.000000248842449e-05,0.9947809902065279
1.000000257072149e-05,0.9947794741444509
1.000000265431582e-05,0.9947779664140061
1.000000273996893e-05,0.9947764538706859
1.000000282853015e-05,0.9947749227137512
1.000000292110379e-05,0.9947733557149886
1.000000301705374e-05,0.9947717652183116
1.000000311124182e-05,0.9947702345092709
1.00000032043878e-05,0.994768747232079
1.000000329752497e-05,0.9947672829657113
1.000000339144949e-05,0.9947658259828719
1.000000348559815e-05,0.994764381567537
1.000000358013992e-05,0.9947629432421766
1.000000360984576e-05,0.9947624934202682
1.000000362941094e-05,0.9947621974251861
1.000000364580032e-05,0.9947619494559734
1.000000365992641e-05,0.9947617356142092
1.000000368023617e-05,0.994761427845121
1.00000037208557e-05,0.9947608109622349
1.000000377873696e-05,0.9947599289552181
1.000000385091237e-05,0.9947588249352221
1.000000389873234e-05,0.9947580911892082
1.000000393745538e-05,0.9947574958153321
1.000000397478845e-05,0.9947569208316971
1.00000040494546e-05,0.994755767960104
1.000000415135038e-05,0.9947541880988238
1.000000425480853e-05,0.9947525759435518
1.000000435899303e-05,0.9947509442885386
1.00000044636937e-05,0.9947492969528688
1.000000456887151e-05,0.9947476358594745
1.000000467586191e-05,0.9947459419341922
1.000000478579736e-05,0.994744200049288
1.000000489991845e-05,0.9947423944391923
1.000000501994854e-05,0.9947405032632648
1.000000514857617e-05,0.9947384919711661
1.00000052749515e-05,0.9947365376004345
1.000000539920231e-05,0.9947346427177595
1.000000552265719e-05,0.9947327909643285
1.000000564641607e-05,0.9947309695988765
1.000000568891179e-05,0.9947303526154557
1.000000571727999e-05,0.9947299430569184
1.000000574276534e-05,0.9947295765165357
1.000000577440913e-05,0.9947291230524185
1.000000579829631e-05,0.9947287819279883
1.000000582519612e-05,0.9947283990546448
1.000000587899576e-05,0.9947276378940654
1.000000596769939e-05,0.9947263984199612
1.000000606785964e-05,0.9947250247369838
1.000000618185515e-05,0.9947234969839458
1.000000629967824e-05,0.9947219588400774
1.000000641258866e-05,0.9947205237607314
1.000000652288367e-05,0.9947191580254308
1.000000663216104e-05,0.9947178390112422
1.000000674190289e-05,0.9947165471775493
1.000000685392799e-05,0.994715260592912
1.00000069700025e-05,0.9947139594963132
1.000000709233987e-05,0.9947126205239366
1.000000722090884e-05,0.994711245367339
1.000000734671161e-05,0.9947099275688009
1.000000747129506e-05,0.9947086454360388
1.000000759665321e-05,0.9947073739781168
1.000000772221627e-05,0.9947061148464641
1.000000777126615e-05,0.9947056259734115
1.000000782133554e-05,0.9947051275344506
1.000000786613413e-05,0.9947046815283571
1.000000789778564e-05,0.994704366279578
1.000000796108864e-05,0.9947037355020932
1.000000806529526e-05,0.9947026971341191
1.000000819435487e-05,0.9947014121169725
1.000000830982867e-05,0.9947002637431139
1.000000840754626e-05,0.9946992931686937
1.00000085014865e-05,0.9946983613922133
1.000000861054162e-05,0.9946972817612986
1.000000874590411e-05,0.994695946048346
1.000000888785934e-05,0.9946945525864901
1.000000903660687e-05,0.9946931035422636
1.000000919511685e-05,0.9946915759933128
1.000000936019937e-05,0.9946900081445753
1.000000952242876e-05,0.9946884949319772
1.000000962625658e-05,0.9946875424685734
1.00000097169852e-05,0.9946867213688576
1.000000976705168e-05,0.9946862726643977
1.000000981411706e-05,0.9946858534555238
1.000000985539285e-05,0.9946854878065647
1.00000098932452e-05,0.9946851541732215
1.000000996894988e-05,0.9946844923514493
1.000001009216156e-05,0.994683432856735
1.000001023968207e-05,0.9946821956547776
1.000001039745174e-05,0.9946809118584713
1.000001054836692e-05,0.9946797220973723
1.000001069449723e-05,0.9946786049723938
1.000001083923725e-05,0.9946775309378234
1.000001098549747e-05,0.9946764764388487
1.000001113715189e-05,0.9946754130573661
1.000001129891622e-05,0.9946743087867804
1.000001146820278e-05,0.9946731817223159
1.000001163395628e-05,0.9946721017323863
1.000001179966454e-05,0.9946710405978512
1.000001196626142e-05,0.9946699873095377
1.000001210627224e-05,0.9946691080793867
1.000001220688872e-05,0.9946684786036599
1.000001228223803e-05,0.9946680084404247
1.000001243293665e-05,0.9946670717871249
1.000001259918924e-05,0.9946660448658474
1.000001277059668e-05,0.9946649940736355
1.000001294957924e-05,0.9946639069464157
1.000001313497725e-05,0.994662793909845
1.000001333257147e-05,0.9946616253308346
1.000001354670719e-05,0.9946603835076684
1.000001375793967e-05,0.994659187429404
1.000001385557287e-05,0.9946586440678412
1.000001393693855e-05,0.9946581958486254
1.000001402267258e-05,0.9946577284848782
1.000001416762879e-05,0.9946569512946071
1.000001435427747e-05,0.994655976761292
1.000001456058985e-05,0.9946549351384451
1.000001475689488e-05,0.9946539785530615
1.000001494771072e-05,0.9946530797349298
1.000001513881425e-05,0.9946522081006395
1.000001533604671e-05,0.9946513354572405
1.000001554917037e-05,0.994650419035672
1.000001576987037e-05,0.9946494940267255
1.000001598746062e-05,0.9946486010006611
1.000001620699866e-05,0.9946477143697314
1.000001642079041e-05,0.9946468598838203
1.000001657668957e-05,0.9946462416304391
1.000001669684063e-05,0.9946457680612403
1.000001690567197e-05,0.9946449518190725
1.000001712725124e-05,0.9946440964862927
1.000001736477959e-05,0.9946431937836931
1.000001762939966e-05,0.9946422083796085
1.000001781222763e-05,0.9946415408907312
1.000001798505582e-05,0.9946409204050823
1.00000182028559e-05,0.9946401550376267
1.000001836759978e-05,0.9946395896342863
1.000001862176413e-05,0.9946387418550882
1.000001888663825e-05,0.9946378899972205
1.000001913347323e-05,0.994637123897651
1.000001938346244e-05,0.9946363728207761
1.000001964503382e-05,0.9946356100553738
1.000001993894395e-05,0.9946347758508306
1.000002022517352e-05,0.9946339815688131
1.000002051351998e-05,0.9946331950664938
1.000002081154429e-05,0.9946323929068575
1.0000021100824e-05,0.9946316239949066
1.000002137634571e-05,0.994630901745815
1.000002167286478e-05,0.9946301371379255
1.000002196772887e-05,0.9946293913283314
1.000002225343152e-05,0.9946286848578269
1.000002253368907e-05,0.9946280093575638
1.000002287246825e-05,0.9946272174334768
1.0000023218371e-05,0.9946264361700263
1.000002354303623e-05,0.9946257259060937
1.000002387662431e-05,0.9946250159282033
1.000002424938163e-05,0.9946242412634164
1.00000246269008e-05,0.9946234717846166
1.000002501014309e-05,0.9946227023428013
1.000002542186219e-05,0.9946218869170421
1.000002580220259e-05,0.994621144332882
1.000002619298543e-05,0.9946203939281932
1.000002664985007e-05,0.9946195359471112
1.000002709492621e-05,0.994618722206528
1.000002755721259e-05,0.9946179001289566
1.000002800919301e-05,0.9946171168957458
1.000002846323823e-05,0.9946163466813664
1.000002899662735e-05,0.9946154573628087
1.000002952621116e-05,0.994614586584386
1.000003009010739e-05,0.9946136706677405
1.000003062592631e-05,0.9946128116765361
1.000003120580634e-05,0.9946118963489178
1.000003183872337e-05,0.9946109156011458
1.0000032505624e-05,0.9946099054533072
1.000003315863421e-05,0.994608931575942
1.000003388209283e-05,0.9946078638099295
1.000003467459387e-05,0.9946067034634617
1.000003555199008e-05,0.9946054285404693
1.000003641404971e-05,0.9946041860541047
1.00000374352629e-05,0.9946027263679968
1.000003858481798e-05,0.9946011032555411
1.000003975958954e-05,0.9945994538567871
1.000004119309898e-05,0.9945974475366868
1.000004283970223e-05,0.9945951468769756
1.000004492885735e-05,0.9945922259289209
1.000004753900946e-05,0.9945885588289812
1.000005087148431e-05,0.9945838276515905
1.000005576319924e-05,0.9945767471808176
1.000006166865822e-05,0.9945679408755878
1.000006803792893e-05,0.9945580847901293
1.00000749915326e-05,0.9945468623413283
1.000008268308055e-05,0.994533846737599
1.000009134902442e-05,0.9945183761403674
1.000010137733517e-05,0.9944993405031294
1.000011326602512e-05,0.9944750966685247
1.000012779272766e-05,0.9944428319165074
1.000014629748387e-05,0.9943971981034142
1.000017158642438e-05,0.9943259200648634
1.000020413786387e-05,0.9942175968274239
1.000024589146313e-05,0.9940485909081666
1.000029675513636e-05,0.9937925284975321
1.000034852896171e-05,0.9934702956909346
1.000040330112097e-05,0.9930563106679868
1.000046215512419e-05,0.9925219887285529
1.000052553575593e-05,0.9918367951089767
1.000059430560881e-05,0.9909580036231382
1.000066917748661e-05,0.9898340525778833
1.000075091746797e-05,0.9884006235684124
1.000084052473447e-05,0.9865741619571183
1.000093919660572e-05,0.9842470429393175
1.000104850855721e-05,0.9812762029027231
1.000117060307456e-05,0.977466181416946
1.000130837843166e-05,0.9725452443262916
1.000146585522567e-05,0.9661256069041595
1.000164878386991e-05,0.95763705074296
1.000186501128021e-05,0.9462503762443557
1.000210166855097e-05,0.9322402633354834
1.000236241771737e-05,0.9151424889250708
1.000265330407017e-05,0.89433707413838
1.000298753410511e-05,0.8686846163452085
1.000339765591374e-05,0.8355557615574202
1.000386899834488e-05,0.7966723418393613
1.000433205562225e-05,0.7593439545604538
1.0004762164901e-05,0.7270586005020436
1.000518898529912e-05,0.6986642016699188
1.000554210302633e-05,0.678550250353574
1.00058048115096e-05,0.6657498724584925
1.000604292600391e-05,0.6557758609061028
1.000627941766609e-05,0.6473563735623106
1.000653039150777e-05,0.6399299474323672
1.000681143114172e-05,0.6332586619834625
1.000714248104563e-05,0.6272815927877741
1.000758353624931e-05,0.6217397057691287
1.00080971222087e-05,0.6176665266234218
1.00085424418103e-05,0.6154226559058353
1.00089393872849e-05,0.6139369803117675
1.000932546815675e-05,0.612640015606456
1.000971536918901e-05,0.6112842331357695
1.00101247023659e-05,0.6097044697650221
1.001056856876134e-05,0.6077781688473375
1.001106769877457e-05,0.6053904658143408
1.001166310608877e-05,0.6023738585495449
1.001247731281763e-05,0.5982681671688386
1.001377265479618e-05,0.5924161022536596
1.001472401226565e-05,0.5887914010958361
1.00156622028042e-05,0.5857434452779856
1.001676981089146e-05,0.5826381581423392
1.001849086536233e-05,0.5784247585793747
1.002038057243813e-05,0.5743298920238227
1.002222970329941e-05,0.5707332059499056
1.002462173089612e-05,0.5666045497746564
1.002915562104725e-05,0.560053639169687
1.00353290424155e-05,0.5529451807222816
1.004197849996181e-05,0.5467682484090578
1.004980247971832e-05,0.5407508949704001
1.005965454315778e-05,0.5344461431631284
1.007206743598258e-05,0.5278358190846818
1.008726325779762e-05,0.5210618193493033
1.010580544779513e-05,0.5140709080106317
1.012865878989183e-05,0.5067012136972694
1.015431426091431e-05,0.4995081540249607
1.018507212608292e-05,0.4918810117875541
1.022277618796079e-05,0.4835195682330973
1.026863415473842e-05,0.474324361614948
1.032464455308956e-05,0.4640551335990189
1.03933478012532e-05,0.4524270789182594
1.047732361549498e-05,0.4392324519734341
1.057829209545311e-05,0.4245347210237495
1.068019061804684e-05,0.4108729954152436
1.077572372871385e-05,0.3990859442518824
1.086702963175535e-05,0.3886840831680719
1.095593289927427e-05,0.3792979192143396
1.104368612099984e-05,0.3706876005313027
1.113178336377667e-05,0.3626439798897289
1.122155355395862e-05,0.3550223747905367
1.131416990765812e-05,0.3477309642256254
1.141091376907403e-05,0.3407051699836454
1.151337268496703e-05,0.3338984307306742
1.162377762310829e-05,0.327275116659704
1.174579695129886e-05,0.3207983744347273
1.188676093376742e-05,0.3144023033938241
1.205620507372069e-05,0.3082162184286389
1.223676422157905e-05,0.3033160638357428
1.242564954382792e-05,0.2998109975480774
1.259472236955133e-05,0.2977851898604715
1.274451346660159e-05,0.2966294741170462
1.288424739776071e-05,0.2959272468302633
1.301718969360736e-05,0.2954883293611281
1.314555695921362e-05,0.295207065193881
1.327178097152493e-05,0.2950215873358133
1.339751574510446e-05,0.2948964950376146
1.352393651973575e-05,0.2948105382595573
1.365208866338681e-05,0.2947504240623905
1.37829026524549e-05,0.2947076916563772
1.391723811031597e-05,0.294676851811356
1.405595678507018e-05,0.2946542743701033
1.419996297450784e-05,0.2946375219425273
1.435023711116193e-05,0.2946249350192233
1.450787599326658e-05,0.2946153682072037
1.467413719221179e-05,0.294608020729467
1.485049190840181e-05,0.2946023258732474
1.503869322688409e-05,0.2945978778658408
1.523869322688409e-05,0.2945944154285423
1.543869322688409e-05,0.2945918571654833
1.563869322688409e-05,0.2945899360251759
1.583869322688409e-05,0.2945884733808214
1.603869322688409e-05,0.2945873469770687
1.623869322688409e-05,0.2945864712333306
1.643869322688409e-05,0.2945857850080013
1.66386932268841e-05,0.2945852438090698
1.68386932268841e-05,0.2945848147247997
1.70386932268841e-05,0.2945844730555875
1.72386932268841e-05,0.2945842000305808
1.74386932268841e-05,0.2945839812294173
1.76386932268841e-05,0.2945838054711099
1.78386932268841e-05,0.2945836640182371
1.803869322688411e-05,0.2945835499977884
1.823869322688411e-05,0.2945834579734439
1.843869322688411e-05,0.2945833836254935
1.863869322688411e-05,0.2945833235084082
1.883869322688411e-05,0.294583274865283
1.903869322688411e-05,0.2945832354845029
1.923869322688411e-05,0.2945832035881197
1.943869322688412e-05,0.2945831777443207
1.963869322688412e-05,0.2945831567984094
1.983869322688412e-05,0.2945831398180792
2e-05,0.2945831285248367

}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
            use comma,
            1000 sep={},
    set decimal separator={,},
    clip marker paths=true,
    grid style={densely dotted, draw=black},
    x tick style={color=black},
    y tick style={color=black},
    }}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h!tbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=5cm,
height=10cm,
at={(0.790898in,0.967508in)},
scale only axis,
grid style={densely dotted},
%enlarge x limits=.1,
xmin=-10,
xmax=60,
domain=-10:60,
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0,
ymax=1.2,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=black},
]


\addplot [color=red,solid,line width=1.5pt]
  table [x expr=\thisrow{/net22 X}*1e9 - 10e3, y={/net22 Y}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[data.csv](http://www19.zippyshare.com/v/Yc8p40T5/file.html)

Comment: can you not rescale the data before giving it to tikz (or any plotting program) given the resolution of a typical printer plotting `4.331319308127319e-10` is likely to be doing a lot of work for no visible gain.

Comment: I'm already adjusting the data with  'table [x expr=\thisrow{/net22 X}*1e9 - 10e3, y={/net22 Y}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};' and at the end tikz has only a small area to plot because in this particulat plot most points are not used

Comment: but with tex fixed point arithmetic 1e-10 * 1e9 is more or less going to be 0*1e9 .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a data that varies over at least 5 order of magnitude and you are thinking of changing pgfplots instead of logarithms.

First, pgfplots is TikZ so if pgfplots cannot handle then TikZ at 99% of the cases won't too because internally everything is mapped back to low level PGF paths. So that is not going to get you anywhere.

Then, what you are basically doing is drawing this inherently log curve and then zoom in to its tiny portion. Because pgfplots works like that. You change `xmin/xmax` values but the curve is generated anyhow. If you want to restrict the curve to a particular domain then you use the properly named `restrict x to domain=..:..` key. Then pgfplots will discard the values before the curve is actually constructed which saves both time and effort.

Example with an exciting curve,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{semilogxaxis}[grid=major,ymin=0,ymax=1.2,
restrict x to domain=5.6:5.8,% Since log axis, we restrict in terms of the exponent 
log basis x = 10,
]
\addplot [color=red,solid,line width=1.5pt]
  table [x expr=\thisrow{/net22 X}*1e9 - 10e3, y={/net22 Y}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually tried to achieve something similar with 'domain=-10:60' but it didn't really work.

Answer (score 2):

If I rescale the X axis a bit I get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
/net22 X,/net22 Y
0,1.02826216146185
4.331319308127319e-04,1.025595622568344
5.019136824735054e-04,1.025111934866457
6.394771857950523e-04,1.024007498889289
7.398554712989986e-04,1.023075577928214
8.583054108782335e-04,1.021843167895365
1.026427625279524e-03,1.019878594742247
1.175565037914328e-03,1.0179605576024
1.351354116919862e-03,1.015546548552447
1.594285380510821e-03,1.01206577259123
1.959949157603062e-03,1.006856077470933
2.356838910393234e-03,1.00166954938047
2.652546177571678e-03,0.9983209342962833
2.922080949098272e-03,0.995757674237659
3.182111086403913e-03,0.9937702321468064
3.440448014594548e-03,0.9922711538444744
3.711816987672119e-03,0.9911786446724034
4.006612198819403e-03,0.9904898827842833
4.339130588465944e-03,0.9902282894968941
4.738531257358337e-03,0.9904510268542126
5.333367998864634e-03,0.9913939730692772
5.803571328059038e-03,0.9923682360412974
6.277404020822525e-03,0.9933270420931612
6.73094944437229e-03,0.9940944135556163
7.174592835913752e-03,0.9946431953278941
7.637860895131457e-03,0.994992493329386
8.143984952344972e-03,0.9951459771039093
8.734058640251291e-03,0.9951088776132965
9.512513843471484e-03,0.9948803911645306
1.039956361510021e-02,0.9945768448822899
1.132030797643451e-02,0.9943505241249664
1.219318961264376e-02,0.9942570465719639
1.313178033099918e-02,0.9942612659118217
1.429368459685971e-02,0.9943309014821656
1.657015023652314e-02,0.9944312704679185
1.837899409640984e-02,0.9944426577451113
2.030654181577978e-02,0.9944214555407267
2.315380905065453e-02,0.9943996768306217
2.732743205663546e-02,0.9943995543440359
3.189152964187356e-02,0.9944054855786713
4.101972481234976e-02,0.994406302505255
5.265870592437432e-02,0.9944053208789571
7.593666814842344e-02,0.9944053356389847
1.188183335701361e-01,0.9944053902724225
2.045816644135613e-01,0.9944053829371198
3.761083261004119e-01,0.9944053826446062
5.761083261004118e-01,0.9944053827390887
7.761083261004118e-01,0.9944053827370866
9.761083261004119e-01,0.9944053827369277
1.176108326100412e+00,0.994405382736939
1.376108326100412e+00,0.994405382736939
1.576108326100412e+00,0.9944053827369391
1.776108326100412e+00,0.9944053827369397
1.976108326100412e+00,0.9944053827369395
2.176108326100412e+00,0.9944053827369393
2.376108326100412e+00,0.9944053827369391
2.576108326100412e+00,0.9944053827369387
2.776108326100413e+00,0.9944053827369388
2.976108326100413e+00,0.9944053827369389
3.176108326100413e+00,0.9944053827369386
3.376108326100413e+00,0.9944053827369386
3.576108326100414e+00,0.9944053827369388
3.776108326100414e+00,0.9944053827369389
3.976108326100414e+00,0.9944053827369388
4.176108326100414e+00,0.9944053827369397
4.376108326100413e+00,0.9944053827369387
4.576108326100413e+00,0.9944053827369387
4.776108326100413e+00,0.9944053827369387
4.976108326100413e+00,0.9944053827369388
5.176108326100413e+00,0.9944053827369387
5.376108326100412e+00,0.9944053827369386
5.576108326100412e+00,0.9944053827369385
5.776108326100412e+00,0.9944053827369383
5.976108326100412e+00,0.9944053827369386
6.176108326100411e+00,0.9944053827369389
6.376108326100411e+00,0.9944053827369388
6.576108326100411e+00,0.9944053827369385
6.776108326100411e+00,0.9944053827369385
6.976108326100411e+00,0.9944053827369388
7.17610832610041e+00,0.9944053827369389
7.37610832610041e+00,0.9944053827369388
7.57610832610041e+00,0.9944053827369385
7.776108326100411e+00,0.9944053827369393
7.97610832610041e+00,0.9944053827369393
8.17610832610041e+00,0.9944053827369385
8.37610832610041e+00,0.9944053827369387
8.57610832610041e+00,0.9944053827369388
8.776108326100409e+00,0.9944053827369388
8.976108326100409e+00,0.9944053827369383
9.176108326100409e+00,0.9944053827369386
9.376108326100409e+00,0.9944053827369389
9.576108326100409e+00,0.9944053827369387
9.776108326100408e+00,0.9944053827369386
9.888054163050205e+00,0.9944053827369391
1e+01,0.9944053827369387
1.000000031305744e+01,0.9945026442743422
1.000000034044997e+01,0.9945123027671998
1.000000038140491e+01,0.9945273197625016
1.000000042051929e+01,0.9945422748065738
1.000000046366599e+01,0.9945592799216566
1.000000050047185e+01,0.9945740634174881
1.000000053641175e+01,0.9945886323471639
1.000000057460895e+01,0.9946041646469259
1.000000061627338e+01,0.994621078788969
1.000000066304477e+01,0.9946399535511581
1.000000071615235e+01,0.994661170029568
1.000000077698145e+01,0.9946851165182624
1.000000084755945e+01,0.994712310457373
1.000000092353141e+01,0.99474067311982
1.0000001e+01,0.9947680624004441
1.000000100391882e+01,0.9947693904672034
1.000000100806786e+01,0.9947707632190462
1.000000101497031e+01,0.9947729466221733
1.000000102541984e+01,0.9947760124171113
1.000000103920431e+01,0.9947796433614234
1.00000010526573e+01,0.9947827717512592
1.000000106696285e+01,0.9947856944710599
1.000000108279457e+01,0.9947884993724078
1.000000110082991e+01,0.9947912154962885
1.000000112139743e+01,0.9947937800929507
1.000000114307349e+01,0.994795963858575
1.000000116589546e+01,0.9947977842298714
1.000000119003025e+01,0.9947992703274012
1.000000121565269e+01,0.9948004469168495
1.000000124305054e+01,0.9948013382392805
1.000000127252544e+01,0.9948019618074956
1.00000013044161e+01,0.994802330869087
1.000000133913125e+01,0.9948024554653568
1.000000137717766e+01,0.9948023424047657
1.000000141798923e+01,0.9948020069292224
1.000000146469327e+01,0.9948014294369252
1.00000015174084e+01,0.9948006070984314
1.000000157759394e+01,0.9947995245447283
1.000000161749989e+01,0.9947987479204673
1.000000163509705e+01,0.9947983941799829
1.000000164640024e+01,0.9947981642283803
1.000000165604756e+01,0.9947979665982661
1.000000166612771e+01,0.994797758928084
1.000000167674457e+01,0.9947975390185879
1.000000169797828e+01,0.9947970960193985
1.000000173992938e+01,0.9947962112497323
1.000000178918952e+01,0.9947951619841334
1.000000184193857e+01,0.9947940332176113
1.000000188524007e+01,0.9947931068422322
1.00000019177271e+01,0.9947924137602339
1.000000198270115e+01,0.9947910374626118
1.000000206894388e+01,0.9947892365649708
1.000000215577018e+01,0.9947874578409843
1.00000022410274e+01,0.9947857472830879
1.000000232458782e+01,0.9947841063002641
1.000000240667773e+01,0.9947825283986764
1.000000248842449e+01,0.9947809902065279
1.000000257072149e+01,0.9947794741444509
1.000000265431582e+01,0.9947779664140061
1.000000273996893e+01,0.9947764538706859
1.000000282853015e+01,0.9947749227137512
1.000000292110379e+01,0.9947733557149886
1.000000301705374e+01,0.9947717652183116
1.000000311124182e+01,0.9947702345092709
1.00000032043878e+01,0.994768747232079
1.000000329752497e+01,0.9947672829657113
1.000000339144949e+01,0.9947658259828719
1.000000348559815e+01,0.994764381567537
1.000000358013992e+01,0.9947629432421766
1.000000360984576e+01,0.9947624934202682
1.000000362941094e+01,0.9947621974251861
1.000000364580032e+01,0.9947619494559734
1.000000365992641e+01,0.9947617356142092
1.000000368023617e+01,0.994761427845121
1.00000037208557e+01,0.9947608109622349
1.000000377873696e+01,0.9947599289552181
1.000000385091237e+01,0.9947588249352221
1.000000389873234e+01,0.9947580911892082
1.000000393745538e+01,0.9947574958153321
1.000000397478845e+01,0.9947569208316971
1.00000040494546e+01,0.994755767960104
1.000000415135038e+01,0.9947541880988238
1.000000425480853e+01,0.9947525759435518
1.000000435899303e+01,0.9947509442885386
1.00000044636937e+01,0.9947492969528688
1.000000456887151e+01,0.9947476358594745
1.000000467586191e+01,0.9947459419341922
1.000000478579736e+01,0.994744200049288
1.000000489991845e+01,0.9947423944391923
1.000000501994854e+01,0.9947405032632648
1.000000514857617e+01,0.9947384919711661
1.00000052749515e+01,0.9947365376004345
1.000000539920231e+01,0.9947346427177595
1.000000552265719e+01,0.9947327909643285
1.000000564641607e+01,0.9947309695988765
1.000000568891179e+01,0.9947303526154557
1.000000571727999e+01,0.9947299430569184
1.000000574276534e+01,0.9947295765165357
1.000000577440913e+01,0.9947291230524185
1.000000579829631e+01,0.9947287819279883
1.000000582519612e+01,0.9947283990546448
1.000000587899576e+01,0.9947276378940654
1.000000596769939e+01,0.9947263984199612
1.000000606785964e+01,0.9947250247369838
1.000000618185515e+01,0.9947234969839458
1.000000629967824e+01,0.9947219588400774
1.000000641258866e+01,0.9947205237607314
1.000000652288367e+01,0.9947191580254308
1.000000663216104e+01,0.9947178390112422
1.000000674190289e+01,0.9947165471775493
1.000000685392799e+01,0.994715260592912
1.00000069700025e+01,0.9947139594963132
1.000000709233987e+01,0.9947126205239366
1.000000722090884e+01,0.994711245367339
1.000000734671161e+01,0.9947099275688009
1.000000747129506e+01,0.9947086454360388
1.000000759665321e+01,0.9947073739781168
1.000000772221627e+01,0.9947061148464641
1.000000777126615e+01,0.9947056259734115
1.000000782133554e+01,0.9947051275344506
1.000000786613413e+01,0.9947046815283571
1.000000789778564e+01,0.994704366279578
1.000000796108864e+01,0.9947037355020932
1.000000806529526e+01,0.9947026971341191
1.000000819435487e+01,0.9947014121169725
1.000000830982867e+01,0.9947002637431139
1.000000840754626e+01,0.9946992931686937
1.00000085014865e+01,0.9946983613922133
1.000000861054162e+01,0.9946972817612986
1.000000874590411e+01,0.994695946048346
1.000000888785934e+01,0.9946945525864901
1.000000903660687e+01,0.9946931035422636
1.000000919511685e+01,0.9946915759933128
1.000000936019937e+01,0.9946900081445753
1.000000952242876e+01,0.9946884949319772
1.000000962625658e+01,0.9946875424685734
1.00000097169852e+01,0.9946867213688576
1.000000976705168e+01,0.9946862726643977
1.000000981411706e+01,0.9946858534555238
1.000000985539285e+01,0.9946854878065647
1.00000098932452e+01,0.9946851541732215
1.000000996894988e+01,0.9946844923514493
1.000001009216156e+01,0.994683432856735
1.000001023968207e+01,0.9946821956547776
1.000001039745174e+01,0.9946809118584713
1.000001054836692e+01,0.9946797220973723
1.000001069449723e+01,0.9946786049723938
1.000001083923725e+01,0.9946775309378234
1.000001098549747e+01,0.9946764764388487
1.000001113715189e+01,0.9946754130573661
1.000001129891622e+01,0.9946743087867804
1.000001146820278e+01,0.9946731817223159
1.000001163395628e+01,0.9946721017323863
1.000001179966454e+01,0.9946710405978512
1.000001196626142e+01,0.9946699873095377
1.000001210627224e+01,0.9946691080793867
1.000001220688872e+01,0.9946684786036599
1.000001228223803e+01,0.9946680084404247
1.000001243293665e+01,0.9946670717871249
1.000001259918924e+01,0.9946660448658474
1.000001277059668e+01,0.9946649940736355
1.000001294957924e+01,0.9946639069464157
1.000001313497725e+01,0.994662793909845
1.000001333257147e+01,0.9946616253308346
1.000001354670719e+01,0.9946603835076684
1.000001375793967e+01,0.994659187429404
1.000001385557287e+01,0.9946586440678412
1.000001393693855e+01,0.9946581958486254
1.000001402267258e+01,0.9946577284848782
1.000001416762879e+01,0.9946569512946071
1.000001435427747e+01,0.994655976761292
1.000001456058985e+01,0.9946549351384451
1.000001475689488e+01,0.9946539785530615
1.000001494771072e+01,0.9946530797349298
1.000001513881425e+01,0.9946522081006395
1.000001533604671e+01,0.9946513354572405
1.000001554917037e+01,0.994650419035672
1.000001576987037e+01,0.9946494940267255
1.000001598746062e+01,0.9946486010006611
1.000001620699866e+01,0.9946477143697314
1.000001642079041e+01,0.9946468598838203
1.000001657668957e+01,0.9946462416304391
1.000001669684063e+01,0.9946457680612403
1.000001690567197e+01,0.9946449518190725
1.000001712725124e+01,0.9946440964862927
1.000001736477959e+01,0.9946431937836931
1.000001762939966e+01,0.9946422083796085
1.000001781222763e+01,0.9946415408907312
1.000001798505582e+01,0.9946409204050823
1.00000182028559e+01,0.9946401550376267
1.000001836759978e+01,0.9946395896342863
1.000001862176413e+01,0.9946387418550882
1.000001888663825e+01,0.9946378899972205
1.000001913347323e+01,0.994637123897651
1.000001938346244e+01,0.9946363728207761
1.000001964503382e+01,0.9946356100553738
1.000001993894395e+01,0.9946347758508306
1.000002022517352e+01,0.9946339815688131
1.000002051351998e+01,0.9946331950664938
1.000002081154429e+01,0.9946323929068575
1.0000021100824e+01,0.9946316239949066
1.000002137634571e+01,0.994630901745815
1.000002167286478e+01,0.9946301371379255
1.000002196772887e+01,0.9946293913283314
1.000002225343152e+01,0.9946286848578269
1.000002253368907e+01,0.9946280093575638
1.000002287246825e+01,0.9946272174334768
1.0000023218371e+01,0.9946264361700263
1.000002354303623e+01,0.9946257259060937
1.000002387662431e+01,0.9946250159282033
1.000002424938163e+01,0.9946242412634164
1.00000246269008e+01,0.9946234717846166
1.000002501014309e+01,0.9946227023428013
1.000002542186219e+01,0.9946218869170421
1.000002580220259e+01,0.994621144332882
1.000002619298543e+01,0.9946203939281932
1.000002664985007e+01,0.9946195359471112
1.000002709492621e+01,0.994618722206528
1.000002755721259e+01,0.9946179001289566
1.000002800919301e+01,0.9946171168957458
1.000002846323823e+01,0.9946163466813664
1.000002899662735e+01,0.9946154573628087
1.000002952621116e+01,0.994614586584386
1.000003009010739e+01,0.9946136706677405
1.000003062592631e+01,0.9946128116765361
1.000003120580634e+01,0.9946118963489178
1.000003183872337e+01,0.9946109156011458
1.0000032505624e+01,0.9946099054533072
1.000003315863421e+01,0.994608931575942
1.000003388209283e+01,0.9946078638099295
1.000003467459387e+01,0.9946067034634617
1.000003555199008e+01,0.9946054285404693
1.000003641404971e+01,0.9946041860541047
1.00000374352629e+01,0.9946027263679968
1.000003858481798e+01,0.9946011032555411
1.000003975958954e+01,0.9945994538567871
1.000004119309898e+01,0.9945974475366868
1.000004283970223e+01,0.9945951468769756
1.000004492885735e+01,0.9945922259289209
1.000004753900946e+01,0.9945885588289812
1.000005087148431e+01,0.9945838276515905
1.000005576319924e+01,0.9945767471808176
1.000006166865822e+01,0.9945679408755878
1.000006803792893e+01,0.9945580847901293
1.00000749915326e+01,0.9945468623413283
1.000008268308055e+01,0.994533846737599
1.000009134902442e+01,0.9945183761403674
1.000010137733517e+01,0.9944993405031294
1.000011326602512e+01,0.9944750966685247
1.000012779272766e+01,0.9944428319165074
1.000014629748387e+01,0.9943971981034142
1.000017158642438e+01,0.9943259200648634
1.000020413786387e+01,0.9942175968274239
1.000024589146313e+01,0.9940485909081666
1.000029675513636e+01,0.9937925284975321
1.000034852896171e+01,0.9934702956909346
1.000040330112097e+01,0.9930563106679868
1.000046215512419e+01,0.9925219887285529
1.000052553575593e+01,0.9918367951089767
1.000059430560881e+01,0.9909580036231382
1.000066917748661e+01,0.9898340525778833
1.000075091746797e+01,0.9884006235684124
1.000084052473447e+01,0.9865741619571183
1.000093919660572e+01,0.9842470429393175
1.000104850855721e+01,0.9812762029027231
1.000117060307456e+01,0.977466181416946
1.000130837843166e+01,0.9725452443262916
1.000146585522567e+01,0.9661256069041595
1.000164878386991e+01,0.95763705074296
1.000186501128021e+01,0.9462503762443557
1.000210166855097e+01,0.9322402633354834
1.000236241771737e+01,0.9151424889250708
1.000265330407017e+01,0.89433707413838
1.000298753410511e+01,0.8686846163452085
1.000339765591374e+01,0.8355557615574202
1.000386899834488e+01,0.7966723418393613
1.000433205562225e+01,0.7593439545604538
1.0004762164901e+01,0.7270586005020436
1.000518898529912e+01,0.6986642016699188
1.000554210302633e+01,0.678550250353574
1.00058048115096e+01,0.6657498724584925
1.000604292600391e+01,0.6557758609061028
1.000627941766609e+01,0.6473563735623106
1.000653039150777e+01,0.6399299474323672
1.000681143114172e+01,0.6332586619834625
1.000714248104563e+01,0.6272815927877741
1.000758353624931e+01,0.6217397057691287
1.00080971222087e+01,0.6176665266234218
1.00085424418103e+01,0.6154226559058353
1.00089393872849e+01,0.6139369803117675
1.000932546815675e+01,0.612640015606456
1.000971536918901e+01,0.6112842331357695
1.00101247023659e+01,0.6097044697650221
1.001056856876134e+01,0.6077781688473375
1.001106769877457e+01,0.6053904658143408
1.001166310608877e+01,0.6023738585495449
1.001247731281763e+01,0.5982681671688386
1.001377265479618e+01,0.5924161022536596
1.001472401226565e+01,0.5887914010958361
1.00156622028042e+01,0.5857434452779856
1.001676981089146e+01,0.5826381581423392
1.001849086536233e+01,0.5784247585793747
1.002038057243813e+01,0.5743298920238227
1.002222970329941e+01,0.5707332059499056
1.002462173089612e+01,0.5666045497746564
1.002915562104725e+01,0.560053639169687
1.00353290424155e+01,0.5529451807222816
1.004197849996181e+01,0.5467682484090578
1.004980247971832e+01,0.5407508949704001
1.005965454315778e+01,0.5344461431631284
1.007206743598258e+01,0.5278358190846818
1.008726325779762e+01,0.5210618193493033
1.010580544779513e+01,0.5140709080106317
1.012865878989183e+01,0.5067012136972694
1.015431426091431e+01,0.4995081540249607
1.018507212608292e+01,0.4918810117875541
1.022277618796079e+01,0.4835195682330973
1.026863415473842e+01,0.474324361614948
1.032464455308956e+01,0.4640551335990189
1.03933478012532e+01,0.4524270789182594
1.047732361549498e+01,0.4392324519734341
1.057829209545311e+01,0.4245347210237495
1.068019061804684e+01,0.4108729954152436
1.077572372871385e+01,0.3990859442518824
1.086702963175535e+01,0.3886840831680719
1.095593289927427e+01,0.3792979192143396
1.104368612099984e+01,0.3706876005313027
1.113178336377667e+01,0.3626439798897289
1.122155355395862e+01,0.3550223747905367
1.131416990765812e+01,0.3477309642256254
1.141091376907403e+01,0.3407051699836454
1.151337268496703e+01,0.3338984307306742
1.162377762310829e+01,0.327275116659704
1.174579695129886e+01,0.3207983744347273
1.188676093376742e+01,0.3144023033938241
1.205620507372069e+01,0.3082162184286389
1.223676422157905e+01,0.3033160638357428
1.242564954382792e+01,0.2998109975480774
1.259472236955133e+01,0.2977851898604715
1.274451346660159e+01,0.2966294741170462
1.288424739776071e+01,0.2959272468302633
1.301718969360736e+01,0.2954883293611281
1.314555695921362e+01,0.295207065193881
1.327178097152493e+01,0.2950215873358133
1.339751574510446e+01,0.2948964950376146
1.352393651973575e+01,0.2948105382595573
1.365208866338681e+01,0.2947504240623905
1.37829026524549e+01,0.2947076916563772
1.391723811031597e+01,0.294676851811356
1.405595678507018e+01,0.2946542743701033
1.419996297450784e+01,0.2946375219425273
1.435023711116193e+01,0.2946249350192233
1.450787599326658e+01,0.2946153682072037
1.467413719221179e+01,0.294608020729467
1.485049190840181e+01,0.2946023258732474
1.503869322688409e+01,0.2945978778658408
1.523869322688409e+01,0.2945944154285423
1.543869322688409e+01,0.2945918571654833
1.563869322688409e+01,0.2945899360251759
1.583869322688409e+01,0.2945884733808214
1.603869322688409e+01,0.2945873469770687
1.623869322688409e+01,0.2945864712333306
1.643869322688409e+01,0.2945857850080013
1.66386932268841e+01,0.2945852438090698
1.68386932268841e+01,0.2945848147247997
1.70386932268841e+01,0.2945844730555875
1.72386932268841e+01,0.2945842000305808
1.74386932268841e+01,0.2945839812294173
1.76386932268841e+01,0.2945838054711099
1.78386932268841e+01,0.2945836640182371
1.803869322688411e+01,0.2945835499977884
1.823869322688411e+01,0.2945834579734439
1.843869322688411e+01,0.2945833836254935
1.863869322688411e+01,0.2945833235084082
1.883869322688411e+01,0.294583274865283
1.903869322688411e+01,0.2945832354845029
1.923869322688411e+01,0.2945832035881197
1.943869322688412e+01,0.2945831777443207
1.963869322688412e+01,0.2945831567984094
1.983869322688412e+01,0.2945831398180792
2e+01,0.2945831285248367
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
            use comma,
            1000 sep={},
    set decimal separator={,},
    clip marker paths=true,
    grid style={densely dotted, draw=black},
    x tick style={color=black},
    y tick style={color=black},
    }}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h!tbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=5cm,
height=10cm,
at={(0.790898in,0.967508in)},
scale only axis,
grid style={densely dotted},
%enlarge x limits=.1,
xmin=-10,
xmax=60,
domain=-10:60,
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0,
ymax=1.2,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=black},
]


\addplot [color=red,solid,line width=1.5pt]
  table [x expr=\thisrow{/net22 X}, y={/net22 Y}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm using the same file for an other plot and I think it's a bit problematic to have the same file twice (even so one is resealed) -- mostly because there is always the risk that I might change the file but forget to change the other one. Is there a way to do the calculation in LuaLaTeX cos I'm externalizing the plot per system call anyway.