# pgfplots semilog axis limits

Tags: pgfplots

I read in some posts ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232978/dimension-too-large-for-tikz/233030#233030) is one) that if I'm using `semilogxaxis` in order to limit the domain to [10^a, 10^b] I should give as limits `a:b`:

```
\begin{semilogxaxis}[ 
    restrict x to domain = -1:1,
    % this should limit x to [0.1,10]
  ]
\end{semilogxaxis}
```

However, my code behaves differently, and it seems that it takes as limits an approximation of [e^a, e^b]. More precisely, if I write `restrict x to domain = -5:-.5` the axis limits become `0.007:0.5`. which are close to `e^-5:e^-0.5`, that is `0.00673:0.6065`.

Does anyone understand the weird way limits are computed?

This is close to my original code (I cannot include the data as it's a big file):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      every axis/.style = {
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=left,
        clip=false,
        restrict x to domain = -5:-0.5,
        restrict y to domain = -20:20,
      }
    ]
    \begin{semilogxaxis}
      % plots
    \end{semilogxaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE that can be compiled such that others don't have to guess your preamble and so on.

Comment: Did you give `log basis x = 10` ?

Comment: @marmot I can't create a MWE that gaves the same results as I should include a pretty big data table, however I added the code of the axis environment without plots that gives me the same results if I add the plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `semilogxaxis` uses `e=2:71828` as basis. If you need any other basis, it has to specified with `log basis x`.

Comment: Thank you! I assumed that, seeing `10^x` as thick labels, the basis were 10. However, do you know how limits were approximated when I was using `e` basis?

Comment: I don't think there is any approximation. `e^-5=0.00673794699` and `e^-0.5=0.60653065971`.

Comment: I have now set `-2.2:-0.2` as limit (with basis 10). I wrote `\addplot coordinates {(10^-2.2,-3) (.2,-3)}` and the first point is outside the limits (the plot does not appear), but if I replace first x coordinate with `10^-2.1` it works. Do you know if there is a way to make the limits inclusive?

Comment: I think there is, as 0.0068 is not plotted and 0.007 is plotted, and they are both greater than 0.0067

Comment: @Taekwondavide I think then the upper limit is not included in `semilogxaxis`. For linear x axis, upper limit is also included.

Comment: Nice sun glasses. +1. In our burrow it is so dark that we don't need them. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @marmot. I see that you have stars on the hat that will shine in the darkness. Not bad ;-)